# Reasons for Parallelism In One Block vs Multiple Single Threaded Target Blocks in Task Parallel Dataflow

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, tpl-dataflow

What would be a reason for or difference between creating `n` number of `ITargetBlock<T>` workers without parallelism vs one `ITargetBlock<T>` worker with `MaxDegreeOfParallelism n`?

```
               |-- TransformBlock<T, TOut> BoundedCapacity=1  --|
               |-- TransformBlock<T, TOut> BoundedCapacity=1  --|
BufferBlock<T> |                                                |-- ActionBlock<TOut>
               |-- TransformBlock<T, TOut> BoundedCapacity=1  --|
               |-- TransformBlock<T, TOut> BoundedCapacity=1  --|
```

vs

```
BufferBlock<T>  --  TransformBlock<T, TOut> MaxDegreeOfParallelism=4  --  ActionBlock<TOut>
```

Assuming that the worker block performs long running or I/O bound work, there are plenty of physical processor cores to share, and the order of results in which `TOut` are produced does not matter.

Comment: Well, for one thing, `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` (as its name implies) is a maximum. It doesn't guarantee **exactly** `n` instances. It just guarantees no more than `n` instances.

Comment: At first I would think that's a negative - no guarantee of getting all the parallelism I asked for, but as I commented to @TheGeneral, now I think it can be seen in a positive light as _'I'll give you n threads if you really need them'_...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. That former is less efficient and potentially more allocations depending how you would do this.
2. You would have to control max parallelism from a custom scheduler or some other synchronisation approach
3. You cannot take advantage of the `EnsureOrdered`
4. The overall pipeline has more complexity and has more code to boiler plate
5. It is slightly harder to debug (IMO).

I would just use 1 standard block per 1 standard concern unless there was a compelling need to do otherwise, at which point i would look closely at the benefits a custom block

<sub>***Note** : This answer has glossed over a lot of points (pros and cons) and lacks specific details that might be relevant to your solution which can't be known with the information supplied*</sub>

<sub>***Note 2** : All in all there isn't much difference if all you are doing is running as much work as you can in parallel (apart from the points supplied)*</sub>

Comment: I agree with 4 (complexity) and 5 (debugging) and all other things being equal would count those as negatives. I stated in my assumptions output ordering is not needed. But when you say multiple blocks would need max parallelism control, it seems to me that the exact number of blocks with `BoundedCapacity=1` ensures only exactly that many parallel processes and messages delivered round-robin. If they are all doing the same exact job, I don't understand the need for a custom scheduler. Or did I miss something?

Comment: @mdisibio yeah, boundedCapacity is basically the buffer of the block, "*But when you say multiple blocks would need max parallelism contro*" - my thought was you were creating them dynamically. You are right don't need a custom scheduled or other synchronisation approach to limit max parallelism if you are hardwirering blocks. I think you are pretty on top of the differences.

Comment: @mdisibio i personally would still just go with a single block and turn off ensureordered, with a max degree of parallelism (if needed)

Comment: I agree single block is more straightforward. But your answer did get me thinking. So with hardwiring four blocks I think I am smarter than the library and know that four threads are good for me. But the library is likely much smarter than me and the single parallel-enabled block won't allocate all four threads unless actually needed. I've made a  linear assumption that there will always be four blocks 100% busy all the time...but I have no way of actually knowing that there won't be cycles where one or more blocks are actually idle and I am wasting one or more threads!

Comment: @mdisibio you are playing a dubious game of second guessing TPL, for instance if your methods are async, you can likely have many more await calls than threads/cores, and the scheduler / TPL will manage this better than you will. However, thats not to say you don't know better. but you would have to have a very solid case. If in doubt, you can always profile and benchmark your solutions

Comment: Also thanks for the tip on `EnsuredOrder`. Looks like that's a newer option I've missed!